# ValueError: shapes (1,10) and (2,) not aligned: 10 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, linear-regression

I am running a multiple linear regression using backward elimination. Below is the code

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
X = np.append(arr = np.ones((50, 1)).astype(int), values = X, axis = 
1)
X_opt = X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog= y, exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
X_opt = X[:,[0,1,3,4,5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog= y, exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
X_opt = X[:,[0,3,4,5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog= y, exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
X_opt = X[:,[0,3,5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog= y, exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
X_opt = X[:,[0,3]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog= y, exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
```

But when I am predicting using the above regressor_OLS model,

```
X_new = X[:, 3]
y_pred2 = regressor_OLS.predict(X_new)
```

I am getting the below error:

```
    y_pred2 = regressor_OLS.predict(X_new)
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-263dee38fc26>", line 1, in <module>
    y_pred2 = regressor_OLS.predict(X_new)

  File "/Users/ritesh.satapathy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 749, in predict
    return self.model.predict(self.params, exog, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/ritesh.satapathy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 359, in predict
    return np.dot(exog, params)

ValueError: shapes (1,50) and (2,) not aligned: 50 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

I tried `X_new = X_test[:,3]` but still same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-5020d55a4448>", line 1, in <module>
    y_pred2 = regressor_OLS.predict(X_ne1)

  File "/Users/ritesh.satapathy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 749, in predict
    return self.model.predict(self.params, exog, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/ritesh.satapathy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 359, in predict
    return np.dot(exog, params)

ValueError: shapes (1,10) and (2,) not aligned: 10 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Comment: What's `X` and `y`?

Comment: Why you are adding 50 ones in the 1st column?
X = np.append(arr = np.ones((50, 1)).astype(int), values = X, axis = 1)

Comment: Its impossible to calculate independent value using dependent value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X_ne1 = X_test[:,3]
y_pred2 = regressor_OLS.predict(X_ne1)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
# The confusion occurs due to the two different forms of statsmodels predict() method.
# This is just a consequence of the way the statsmodels folks designed the api.
# Both forms of the predict() method demonstrated and explained below.

import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# random normal x, y with y = x + 10
x = np.random.randn(100)
y = x + np.random.randn(100) + 10

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
ax.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.6, color='blue')
# will add the regression line to the plot and display below.

# Plot a linear regression line through the points in the scatter plot, above.
# Using statsmodels.api.OLS(Y, X).fit().
# To include a regression constant, one must use sm.add_constant() to add a column of '1s'
# to the X matrix. Basically, this tells statsmodels to calculate a constant for the regression line.
#
# FYI, the sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression model includes a fit_intercept parameter
# and does not require the X matrix to have a column of ones.
x_matrix = sm.add_constant(x)
model = sm.OLS(y, x_matrix)
# regression_results is an object: statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.
regression_results = model.fit()
# nice summary
# print(regression_results.summary())

#
# There are two forms of the predict() method:
# There is sm.OLS(y, x).predict(). This predict() method has no knowledge of the fitted coefficients
# produced by model.fit(), above. This is just the way the scipy developers decided to implement
# the linear model.
# The fitted coefficients for the linear model are in RegressionResults and RegressionResults
# has its own predict().
# If you use model.predict(), you need to pass the coefficients. This form of the predict() method
# basically calculates y = ax + b where you pass the coefficients, a and b. This is why the error
# occurs.
#
# Use RegressionResults.predict() which acts as you expect, except that you  still must add
# a column of ones to the x-values used to predict y. This is because the original model
# was fit with a regression constant (intercept). Generally linear models are fit with an intercept
# unless there is some problem-specific reason not to.
#
x_pred = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 50)
# put the X matrix in 'standard' form, i.e. with a column of ones.
x_matrix = sm.add_constant(x_pred)
y_pred = regression_results.predict(x_matrix)

# Line from RegressionResults.predict() in 'black'.
ax.plot(x_pred, y_pred, color='black')
# one more graphic to add before display below.

# So why is model.predict() provided? The calculation for a linear model is a trivial
# linear numpy calculation. For more complex models, this will not be the case
# and model.predict() can be useful.
# Here is how to use it.

coef = regression_results.params[1]     # get the fitted model coefficients
const = regression_results.params[0]

# These two lines of code produce the same results, as expected.
# y_pred = coef * x_pred + const
y_pred = model.predict(params=[const, coef], exog=x_matrix)

# Line from model.predict() in 'purple' overlays the 'black' line from above.
ax.plot(x_pred, y_pred, color='purple')


plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Best working reality check on statsmodels and array expectations I've come across, thank you @tmck!

Comment: The only answer that solved the issue for me! So, if you write code like `model.fit()`, then run `model.predict()`, it won't work. What you need to do is assign the result of `model.fit()` to a parameter, and then run predict on that. For exapmle: `model_results = model.fit(); model_results.predict(test_set)`

Comment: That's one way Corey, but I would use OLSResults.get_prediction() which returns a PredictionResults object with confidence intervals for predictions; both in-sample and out-of-sample. Since posting this answer I wrote down everything I know about statsmodels OLS here: https://www.mlbridgeresearch.com/articles/ols1

Answer (score 2):

You also need to drop the columns that corresponded to the one you dropped while building a more optimized regressor.

```py
X_new = X_test[:, [0,3]] 
y2_pred = regressor_OLS.predict(X_new)
```

Also you will need to use the predict on your test set which is not clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take columns from X as you have already defined X_opt. 
Also you shouldn't use 3 as you have just 2 columns. 
First you need to split the dataset into X_opt_train and X_opt_test and y_train and y_test. Then you fit the dataset to X_opt_train and y_train. And then you predict: 
y_pred = regressor_OLS.predict(X_opt_test)

At least this works for me.I had the same error

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing the following code and there is an error I get when running:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Define the sample frequency and number of samples

fs = 1 # Hz
N = 128

## Generate a sinusoidal signal with two frequencies

#f1 = 50
#f2 = 150
t = np.linspace(0, (N-1)/fs, N)
#x = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*t)
x = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Anghel Cernescu_DELL\Fatigue book\Fatigue load histories\Center Notched Plate GKN\Time history.txt')
print(x)

## Compute the FFT of the signal

X = np.abs(np.fft.fft(x))

## Normalize the FFT results

X = X / N

## Compute the ASD

ASD = X**2

## Determine the frequency range

f = np.linspace(0, fs/2, N//2)

## Generate a random phase spectrum

phase_spectrum = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, N//2)
print(phase_spectrum)

## Create the complex spectrum

complex_spectrum = ASD.dot(np.exp(1j * phase_spectrum))

## Inverse FFT to obtain the time-domain signal

x_reconstructed = np.fft.ifft(complex_spectrum)

## Plot the original and reconstructed signals

plt.plot(t, x, label='Original Signal')
plt.plot(t, x_reconstructed, label='Reconstructed Signal')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('Signal Generation from ASD')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

The error is:
ValueError: shapes (128,) and (64,) not aligned: 128 (dim 0) != 64 (dim 0)

Can someone give me a solution?

Thanks,
Anghel